# What regex should I use here?

Tags: java, regex

I am working on some socket programming stuff and attempting to match some strings. The format is as follows:

```
1.) Some text
```

where the one represents any number, and *some text* refers to anything (including letters, numbers, quotation marks, etc).

I tried using `[0-9]*\\.\\).*` but it doesn't return a match. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

**Edit**
As requested, here is my code:

```
/** Parses data returned by the server */
public void getSocketData(String data) {
    String[] lines = data.split("\\r?\\n");
    this.fileHosts = new String[lines.length];
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*\\.\\).*");
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String line = lines[i];
        if (p.matcher(line).matches()) {
            //The format is: 1.) "b.jpg" from "192.168.1.101:40000"
            String[] info = line.split("\"");
            this.fileHosts[i] = info[3]; //this should now contain <addr:port>
            System.out.println("Adding " + fileHosts[i] + " to fileHosts");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No Match!");
        }
    }
}//getSocketData
```

Comment: Can you post your Java code that makes use of your regex? If it's not because of mismatched backslashes, it's probably the wrong method call or something else.

Comment: @BoltClock, sure thing. I've revised it to add the code.

Comment: +1 For showing what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "1.) Some text";

    System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("^[0-9]+\\.\\).*$","matched"));
}
```

Output:

```
matched
```

EDIT: Same result with the following:

```
String s = "1.) \"b.jpg\" from \"192.168.1.101:40000\"";
```

That is the example in the comment in your code

EDIT2: I try also your code:

```
        String s = "1.) \"b.jpg\" from \"192.168.1.101:40000\"";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+\\.\\).*$"); // works also if you use * instead of +
        if (p.matcher(s).matches()) {
            System.out.println("match");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No Match!");
        }
```

The result is

```
match
```

Try using this regex: `^[0-9]+\\.\\).*$`

Comment: thanks for your help on figuring this out. Your thorough help got you this accept! It turns out that both of our regexes work. Since I was getting the data from one of my sockets, there were extra, *invisible*, characters in my String which was causing it not to match up. Changing my check to `if (p.matcher(line.trim()).matches())` fixed everything.

Comment: The important thing is that we did ;)